# The first queries behave erratically

Tags: mysql, performance, testing

I ran the same query in number of tables (containing different no of records):

```
SELECT * FROM `tblTest`
ORDER BY `tblTest`.`DateAccess` DESC;
```

Why the first queries behave erratically (take longer then second, third...)?

I calculated the average of the second, third and fourth query, exuding the first query.

So for example, in a table with 1,000,000 records, the first time to proccess takes 4.8410 s and second time - only 0.8940 s. Why is this happening?

[image]

p.s. I use phpMyAdmin tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DBMS are really smart applications and maintain multiple catalogues to optimize their execution. When a query is run it generates many entries in the database depending on the DBMS used these catalogues will be more optimized and can even go to automatically generate index to optimize really often used queries. They also all have what is call a query optimizer which analyzes the plan of the query execution in order to optimize the execution plan.

In your specific case, you should look at query and result caching, the following article should help you understand how mysql natively tries to optimize query processing.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache.html

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/enable-the-query-cache-in-mysql-to-improve-performance.html

Here is a comparison between oracle, mysql and postgres (not a new article but will give you a basic idea of how different dbms have different way of handling complex queries on large databases)

http://dcdbappl1.cern.ch:8080/dcdb/archive/ttraczyk/db_compare/db_compare.html#Query+optimization

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at the links you posted. I've started realising that it is something to do with query cache